# ModelCom extension breaks initialization

Tags: jena

I have a class `ModelComExt` that extends `ModelCom`:

```
public class ModelComExt extends ModelCom {
    .
    .
    public ModelComExt() {
           super(ValidationReport.reportConformsTrue().getGraph());
    }
    .
    .
    .
    // no overrides or any manipulation with ModelCom's members
}
```

When I simply create an instance of `ModelComExt`, like that:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JenaSystem.DEBUG_INIT = true;
        new ModelComExt();
    }
       
}
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.fresh(ResourceImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.<init>(ResourceImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory$Impl.createResource(ResourceFactory.java:313)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createResource(ResourceFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS.resource(RDFS.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS$Init.Class(RDFS.java:68)
    at org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS.<clinit>(RDFS.java:40)
    at org.apache.jena.shared.PrefixMapping.<clinit>(PrefixMapping.java:219)
    at com.minimal.failingcase.minimalfailingcase.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:253)
    at org.apache.jena.util.LocationMapper.initFromPath(LocationMapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.jena.util.LocationMapper.getInternal(LocationMapper.java:69)
    at org.apache.jena.util.FileManagerImpl.makeGlobal(FileManagerImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.jena.util.FileManagerImpl.get(FileManagerImpl.java:94)
    at org.apache.jena.util.FileManager.getInternal(FileManager.java:34)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IO_JenaReaders.wireIntoJena(IO_JenaReaders.java:41)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.IO_Jena.wireIntoJena(IO_Jena.java:30)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RIOT.init(RIOT.java:81)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.InitRIOT.start(InitRIOT.java:29)
    at org.apache.jena.base.module.Subsystem.lambda$initialize$2(Subsystem.java:117)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.apache.jena.base.module.Subsystem.forEach(Subsystem.java:193)
    at org.apache.jena.base.module.Subsystem.forEach(Subsystem.java:169)
    at org.apache.jena.base.module.Subsystem.initialize(Subsystem.java:115)
    at org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSystem.init(JenaSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.jena.graph.NodeFactory.<clinit>(NodeFactory.java:32)
```

Jena system INIT debug:

```
Subsystem.init - start
Found:
  JenaInitLevel0       [0]
  InitJenaCore         [10]
  InitRIOT             [20]
  InitARQ              [30]
  InitRDFS             [60]
  InitShacl            [95]
Initialization sequence:
  JenaInitLevel0       [0]
  InitJenaCore         [10]
  InitRIOT             [20]
  InitARQ              [30]
  InitRDFS             [60]
  InitShacl            [95]
Init: JenaInitLevel0
Jena initialization
Init: InitJenaCore
JenaCore.init - start
JenaCore.init - finish
Init: InitRIOT
RIOT.init - start
```

Now comes the interesting part - **this only occurs when there is `location-mapping.ttl` in the directory that gets implicitly loaded**. If there is no `location-mapping.ttl` in the directory and it doesn't get loaded implicitly, this initialization error does not occur and everything gets initialized successfully when instantiating `ModelComExt`.

Edit: Having investigated the nested method calls that occur during `ModelComExt` instantiation, I have observed that the aforementioned error first occurs when `new ModelCom(Factory.createMemGraph())` is called. So the following code produces the same error under the same circumstances (`location-mapping.ttl` is present):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JenaSystem.DEBUG_INIT = true;
        new ModelCom(Factory.createMemGraph());
    }

}
```

Comment: try having a static initializer `static { JenaSystem.init(); }` in class Main.

Comment: Why not create a regular model and copy the validation report into it? To add functionalit, consider working at the graph level using `WrappedGraph` and wrap that with a Model API.

Comment: Indeed, adding the static initializer avoids the `NullPointerException` when `location-mapping.ttl` is on the classpath.